# R: Simulate data with interaction given Y and X

Tags: r, interaction, simulation

I want to simulate an independent variable $Z$ given a dependent variable $Y$ and an independent variable $X$. Specifically, I want to simulate data that fits the following model :

$$Y=b_0+b_1 X+b_2 Z+b_3 XZ+e$$

Below is an example with $b_0 = 1$, $b_1 = 2$, $b_2 = 3$, $b_3 = 4$. I tried to solve for $Z$ :

$${\begin{aligned}
Y&=1+2X+3Z+4XZ+e\\
3Z+4XZ&=Y-1-2X-e\\
Z(3+4X)&=Y-1-2X-e\\
Z&=(Y-1-2X-e)/(3+4X)\\
\end{aligned}}$$

This is my R code :

```
set.seed(1)

n <- 1000
Y <- rnorm(n)
X <- rnorm(n)
e <- rnorm(n)
Z <- (Y - 1 - 2*X - e) / (3 + 4*X)
```

And the output:

```
> lm(Y ~ X*Z)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X * Z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X            Z          X:Z  
     0.5082       1.0191       1.5145       2.0111
```

As can be seen, the coefficient do not match what I had specified beforehand. What am I missing?

Comment: By construction, $Z$ and $e$ are not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you arbitrary set the relation between your variables (by setting the b's), but the actual variables are independent, as you created them by a random draw, notthing in your model actually made them have the relationship that you stabilshed.

For example, Y is a `rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1)` so the intercept b0 should be (as n goes to infinity) 0, not 1 as you wanted it to be

Comment: I did not thought about that, makes sense. Thank you!